# Cron for two times a day

Tags: spring, cron, scheduled-tasks

I would like to schedule a cron job at 5am and 1830

I tried

```
0,30      5,18     *       *       *
```

but this actually run four times a day at

- 0500
- 0530
- 1800
- 1830

Can I set up cron to do this? I am using spring to run this cron job so if I cant do it using standard cron can I do it another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to schedule it with two lines:

```
0      5     *       *       *
30    18     *       *       *
```

There is no way to specify some minutes/hours combination: if you define two couples of them, all combinations will be performed.